# Java Android Calendar/DateFormat this format XXXXXXXX

Tags: java, android, calendar, format

I actually use this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
final String currentDate = 
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());
```

result = wednesday 27 march 2019

I need this : 27032019
Without , / or .
Only XXXXXXXX

Thanks you

Comment: Research SimpleDateFormat. But I think this should work:
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyy")

Comment: try using new java 8 time api's LocalDate. Date is now outdated.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `DateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. `LocalDate.now(yourTimeZone).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMuuuu"))`.

Comment: What do you need `27032019` for? It’s not easily readable by humans and not recommended for serialization (for the latter rather use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: `2019-03-27`).

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the modern answer and some additional thoughts.

For most purposes you should not want your date formatted to `27032019`. It’s not easily readable by humans and not recommended for serialization.

Also consider not using `Calendar`, `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` or `Date`. Those classes are long outdated and poorly designed. Instead you may use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It’s so much nicer to work with.

### Serialization using java.time and ThreeTenABP

If you need your date string to be machine readable — for example if it’s for a JSON or for storing into a text file from where you or someone else needs to read it back — use the standard ISO 8601 format. `LocalDate.toString` produces this format, so we don’t need any explicit formatter:

```
    final String currentDate
            = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Khartoum")).toString();
    System.out.println(currentDate);
```

Output when running today is:

> 2019-03-27

### A compacter ISO 8601 format

If you insist on a compact format without any punctuation, ISO 8601 offers that too:

```
    final String currentDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Khartoum"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
```

> 20190327

### Your format

And if you really insist (I don’t see why you should), java.time can of course produce your requested format too:

```
    final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMuuuu");
    final String currentDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Khartoum"))
            .format(dateFormatter);
```

> 27032019

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages. My imports for the above snippets are:

  ```
  import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
  import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;
  import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;
  ```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
System.out.println("Date : " + format.format(date.getTime()));;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can do is that using short format and taking out the unnecessary parts

```
final String currentDate = 
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(calendar.getTime());
currentDate= currentDate.replace("/"", "");
```

Comment: In en-US locale this gives 32719. There are probably locales where it works, but result varies by locale.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```